# Prevent setting a class attribute to an element

Tags: r, class

How can I be able to throw an error when trying to set a class attribute to an element that does not satisfy a certain criterion?.

For example we see that when we have any object of mode `list`, we cannot set its class attribute to `factor`. ie

```
a <- as.list(1:3)
class(a) <- "factor"
Error in class(a) <- "factor" : 
  adding class "factor" to an invalid object
```

I need to replicate this same idea to `my_class` class. I dont want it to work on a list.
ie

```
a <- as.list(1:3)
class(a) <-"my_class" # SHOULD THROW AN ERROR
attr(a, "class") <- "my_class" # SHOULD THROW AN ERROR.
```

How do I do this in R? Thank you

Comment: Just to be clear you are trying to do this only for a list, right? So `class(a) <-"my_class"` should work for `a <- 1:3` ?

Comment: You can't. This check is done in the underlying C code (search the repro on github for the error message).

Comment: @RonakShah for this example sure. Technically I do have a more complicated problem. But I can use the code here and generalize it the way I need it to be. I just want to how how to throw an error when adding the class attribute

Comment: @Roland Thanks. That is True. Found it on line 529 of the `attrib.c` file in the source code. ie [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/4ea998942d843fc839184cfc48559ecf3cab524c/src/main/attrib.c#L529)

Comment: What's wrong with writing a small function which tests the current class first and then attributes the new class?

Comment: @Tjebo that will not eliminate the problem above. On using the class, someone might try the above and think that they have created a correct object of the class `my_class` yet that would not be the case

Comment: @Onyambu Probably time for you to switch to S4 classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible within the S3 class system. These special checks for a few base S3 classes are implemented in R's C code and it's currently not possible to extend them to other S3 classes. I suggest you switch to S4 classes if you need to enforce object types and don't want to add assertions to all your methods:

```
constructor <- setClass("my_class", slots = c(x="numeric"))
y <- constructor(x = as.list(1:3))
#Error in validObject(.Object) : 
#  invalid class “my_class” object: invalid object for slot "x" in class "my_class": got class "list", should be or extend class "numeric"

y <- constructor(x = 1:3)
y
#An object of class "my_class"
#Slot "x":
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion although we only teach S3 and RC in the course. Can not go beyond what is provided.